# Is there any wisdom behind "and", "or" operators in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, operators, logical-operators

I wonder why ruby give `and`, `or` less precedence than `&&`, `||` , and assign operator? Is there any reason?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

My guess is that's a direct carry-over from Perl. The operators `or` and `and` were added later in Perl 5 for specific situations were lower precedence was desired.

For example, in Perl, here we wish that `||` had lower precedence, so that we could write:

```
try to perform big long hairy complicated action     || die ;
```

and be sure that the `||` was not going to gobble up part of the action. Perl 5 introduced `or`, a new version of `||` that has low precedence, for exactly this purpose.

An example in Ruby where you could use `or` but not `||`:

```
value = possibly_false or raise "foo"
```

If you used `||`, it would be a syntax error.

Comment: Is there a name for the idiom of do_something or die? Does it get used in ruby?

Comment: I don't know of any name for it, but it's fairly common in Ruby.

Comment: Perl leans heavily on die, whereas Ruby uses raise. The advantage of an exception is you can rescue it.

Comment: Although technically you can rescue from a die, people don't usually bother unless it's really important. It's too much of a nuisance.

Answer (score 8):

The difference is precedence. `||`, `&&` have higher precedence than `=`, but `and`, `or` have lower. So while you can do:

```
a = nil || 0
```

You would have to do:

```
a = (nil or 0)
```

to get same effect. If you do:

```
a = nil or 0
```

The result of expression would still be 0, but a value would be nil.

Answer (score 5):

They have very low precedence so that the operands don't have to be wrapped in parentheses, as is sometimes the case with `&&` and `||`.

Answer (score 4):

Being able to control the precedence of your operators is sometimes useful, especially if you are concerned with readability -- extra parenthesis in conditional statements can sometimes obscure the actual logic.

To be frank, though, I think the reason Ruby has the boolean operator precedence levels it does stems mostly from the fact that Matz was a Perl programmer before he ever wrote Ruby, and borrowed much of the core syntax and operators from that language.

Comment: hmm, that explains why ruby is so immature and at the same time so much bloated. Still hard to wrap my head around that..

Answer (score 2):

I believe the idea is specifically to get them below the assignment operators, so you can write logic tests with assignments but without parens.