# i = true and false in Ruby is true?

Tags: ruby

Am I fundamentally misunderstanding Ruby here? I've been writing Ruby code for about 2 years now and just today stumbled on this...

```
ruby-1.8.7-p249 > i = true and false
 => false 
ruby-1.8.7-p249 > i
 => true
```

Could somebody explain what's going on here please? I'm sure it's to spec, but it just seems counter intuitive to me...

Comment: They "why" part is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434842/is-there-any-wisdom-behide-and-or-operator-in-ruby , and the what part is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/372652/what-are-the-ruby-gotchas-a-newbie-should-be-warned-about

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The operators `&&` and `and` have different precedence, and `=` happens to be in between.

```
irb(main):006:0> i = true and false
=> false
irb(main):007:0> i
=> true
irb(main):008:0> i = true && false
=> false
irb(main):009:0> i
=> false
irb(main):010:0>
```

The first is read as `(i = true) and false`, the second as `i = (true && false)`.

Comment: thnx! i didn't realize there was a difference between && and and, I'll read up on that.

Comment: It's a strange quirk of the Ruby language. I encountered this caveat in a "Ruby for Python programmers" article yesterday, on my first day of learning Ruby :)

Comment: i find it odd i've never encountered this problem before because I use this kind of statements all the time. I have to go back and review a ton of code now :(

Comment: It's not just Ruby that does this, Perl also has the same oddness with `and` and `&&` having different precedence.

Comment: Ruby really is too much like Perl in places. There's probably a one-line Perl module so that you can `use Ruby;` and write the rest of your Perl script in Ruby syntax ;)

Answer (score 13):

`and` has lower precedence than `=` so `i = true and false` is parsed as `(i = true) and false`.

So the value `true` is assigned to `i` and then the return value of that operation (which is true) is `and`ed with false, which causes the whole expression to evaluate to `false,` even though `i` still has the value `true`.

Answer (score 3):

Your line is parsed as

```
i = true and false
(i = true) and false
true and false
```

And of course because of `i = true`, `i` will be `true` afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

As I understand your code, it is interpreted as :

- Assign true to i
- Return i and false

The results seems correct.

Answer (score 1):

As others have elucidated above, the keyword `and` is used when you want to put two *different* *statements* on one line. It is just a nicer way of making your code readable.

Thus,

```
 i = true and false
```

implies

```
i = true; false #(a less widely used code layout in ruby)
```

or which is the most straightforward way:

```
  
 i = true
 false
```

So, the output is correct. Otherwise, if you were expecting `false`, then use the *boolean and* `&&`.

Comment: This is strictly speaking incorrect; if the first portion of the statement evaluates to false or nil, the second portion never gets evaluated at all. So, for example, `i = false and do_some_stuff` is very different from `i = false; do_some_stuff`, because if in the former, `do_some_stuff` isn't going to run.