# Ruby logical operators

Tags: ruby, logical-operators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any wisdom behind “and”, “or” operators in Ruby ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434842/is-there-any-wisdom-behind-and-or-operators-in-ruby)

What is the difference, if any, between the following pairs of logical operators?

1. && vs. and
2. || vs. or

Comment: Covered in serveral questions, including [Is there any wisdom behide "and", "or" operator in Ruby ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434842/is-there-any-wisdom-behide-and-or-operator-in-ruby), [Ruby: difference between || and ‘or’](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083112/ruby-difference-between-and-or), [Difference between “and” and && in Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426826/difference-between-and-and-in-ruby).  In short, precedence.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The "word" versions have lower precedence than the "symbol" versions. In fact, they have even lower precedence than assignment.

Comment: This would explain why `@user = User.find_by_id('test2@example.com') or User.find_by_email('test2@example.com')` sets `@user` to nil even though the record exists.