# Ruby's "&&" vs. "and"

Tags: ruby, operator-keyword

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any wisdom behind “and”, “or” operators in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434842/is-there-any-wisdom-behind-and-or-operators-in-ruby)
>   [Ruby logical operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225613/ruby-logical-operators)

Looking for an explanation of Ruby's `and` operator, contrasted with the `&&` operator. I get from [this post](http://www.themomorohoax.com/2008/12/08/and-vs-amperand-in-ruby) that there's a precedence difference, but the author simply recommends against using `and`, rather than revealing what meaningful purpose it might serve in the language.

Additionally, what's the practical reason for using one over the other?

Comment: && is more important (when solving execution order) than and. And same with or.

Comment: I rephrased my question to request an additional answer: what's the practical reason for using one over the other. Like I said, I get the difference in precedence, but what I don't get is when you'd prefer one over the other.

Comment: I think it’s still duplicate. Just matter of taste, since it’s simply syntactic and execution order difference.

Comment: Ok, but the additional understanding and explanation I asked for wasn't provided, so that makes the closure not terribly helpful to people that are left without a complete answer in the future. Can someone go to the original question, and edit the accepted answer to touch on the "why" part of this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`and` is ultra-low-precedence, like in Perl. Many Ruby programmers seem to advocate against `and`, but I think it's to be preferred over `&&` in most cases -- but do understand the difference in precedence!

Comment: Is there a practical reason you'd use one form instead of the other - something where `and` really does the trick that `&&` doesn't, or where `and` makes for shorter/cleaner code?

Comment: I like `and` for simple conditions -- `if x < 5 and y > 3`. That's what Perl's `and` was designed for (because of its ultra-low precedence). OTOH, a lot of Ruby programmers would insist on `&&` there, for reasons that escape me. I'd only use `&&` for complex boolean arithmetic myself.