# Ruby's 'or' vs '||'

Tags: ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between “and” and && in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426826/difference-between-and-and-in-ruby)
>   [Ruby: difference between || and 'or'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083112/ruby-difference-between-and-or)

I had this code (something like this)

```
foo = nil or 4
```

where I wanted `foo` to be either the first value (could be `nil`), or a default 4. When I tested in irb, the output was what I expected it to be. Silly me, I didn't check the value of `foo` later. After a while, I started noticing some errors in my code, and I didn't find the problem until I DID check the value of `foo` back in irb, which was, oh surprise, `nil` instead of the expected 4.

What's the story about `or` vs `||`? Are they supposed to work as replacements? Are there some caveats on using `or` instead of `||`?

Comment: Although I agree that the questions are directly related, and have a near identical answer, they are not the same question. If the first one was expanded to compare `or` vs `||` as well as `and` vs `&&`, I'd agree that they were duplicates.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434842/is-there-any-wisdom-behind-and-or-operators-in-ruby , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3904888/why-and-or-behaves-differently-in-rails , &c.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The issue here is precedence.  `or` has lower precedence than does `||`.  So, your first statement evaluates to

```
(x = nil) or 4
```

The result of the *expression* is `4` (which is why you thought it was working correctly in `irb`), but `x` is assigned `nil` because `or` has lower precedence than does `=`.

The `||` version does what you want:

```
x = (nil || 4)
```

Answer (score 4):

`or` has lower precedence than both `||` and `=` - that means assignment is executed before `or`. While `||` has higher precedence than `=` and is executed first.

Answer (score 2):

`or` has (very) lower precedence.